# CSS : Style the span within div element

Tags: html, css

My html sode snippet is

```
<div id="head">
   <span id="span1"> </span>
   <span id="span2"> </span>
</div>
```

I am not getting my css working.

```
#head>#span1{
  //its not working.
}
```

I have also tried

```
#head1:nth-child(1){
   width: 200px;
   height: 300px;
   background-color: #0000FF;
}

#head1:nth-child(2){
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   background-color: #0000FF;
 }
```

please help me out.

Comment: There is no element with an ID of `span`. And no element with an ID of `head1`.

Comment: I am sorry sir, my bad. I have updated it, but not working

Comment: If possible, say hownitnis not working. Like, it only does the bg color or it is not setting height or something.

Comment: You can only use #span1 and #span2 to style them. Most of the time we only give id's to elements so we can select them only with id selector (Because id should be unique per page).

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `#head span` to select all `<span>`

Check this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/html-viewer/37ad81dcdb72).

```css
#head span{
   width: 200px;
   height: 300px;
   background-color: #0000FF;
   display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<div id="head">
   <span id="span1">Lorem Ipsum </span>
   <span id="span2">Lorem Ipsum </span>
</div>
```

Try to use `#head #spanN` to select the N `<span>`

```css
#head #span1{
   width: 200px;
   height: 300px;
   background-color: #0000FF;
   display:inline-block
}

#head #span2{
   width: 200px;
   height: 300px;
   background-color: #FF0000;
   display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<div id="head">
   <span id="span1">Lorem Ipsum</span>
   <span id="span2">Lorem Ipsum</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<span>` in an inline element so you need to set `display:block` to make proper styling (in case you need width & height). If you have id all you need to do in your CSS is to target those ids.

```css
#span1{
   width: 200px;
   height: 300px;
   background-color: yellow;
   display:block
}

#span2{
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   background-color: red;
   display:block
 }
```

```html
<div id="head">
   <span id="span1"> </span>
   <span id="span2"> </span>
</div>
```